# Can't uninstall an app

Tags: samsung, uninstallation

I downloaded a locator app not thru google play and after turning off all permissions, it still in my applications.

Comment: Turning off all permissions wouldn't uninstall an app. Clicking on uninstall would do. Are you saying you can't do it? Which application, device and Android version are you using?

Comment: You can't uninstall a system application without root permissions. root permission may voids your warranty, and system apps are built-in app for device, which you see out of the box / first boot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using safe mode?
If not, then try it. I, myself had a similar problem. Using safe mode, I uninstalled it easily.

If you dont know, how to use safe mode, search on google how to enable it on your device.